# How to write a good GetHashCode() implementation for a class that is compared by value?

Tags: c#, hash, gethashcode, consistent-hashing

Let's say we have such a class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Now, let's say two `MyClass` instances are equal when their `SomeValue` property is equal. Thus, I overwrite the `Object.Equals()` and the `Object.GetHashCode()` methods to represent that. `Object.GetHashCode()` returns `SomeValue.GetHashCode()` But at the same time I need to follow these rules:

1. If two instances of an object are equal, they should return the same hash code.
2. The hash code should not change throughout the runtime.

But apparently, `SomeValue` can change, and the hash code we did get before may turn to be invalid.

I can only think of making the class immutable, but I'd like to know what others do in this case.

What do you do in such cases? Is having such a class represents a *subtler problem* in the design decisions?

Comment: Please read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general contract says that if A.equals(B) is true, then their hash codes must be the same. If SomeValue changes in A in such a way that A.equals(B) is no longer true, then A.GetHashCode() can return a different value than before. Mutable objects cannot cache GetHashCode(), it must be calculated every time the method is called.

This article has detailed guidelines for GetHashCode and mutability:

http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/

Comment: Obviously... But if we put A in a hash table and then change the `SomeValue` property, we're in trouble as the hash code is different now. I'm wondering what are the approaches to this problem. One that I can think of is using immutability.

Comment: Yes, that is a limitation of mutability. For example, in Java the documentation for Set says: "Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element." Here is a great blog post on the topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Comment: If you can put the blog article in the answer, I'll choose this one as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your `GetHashCode()` depends on some mutable value you have to change your hash whenever your value changes. Otherwise you break the equals law.

The part, that a hash should never be changed, once somebody asked for it, is needed if you put your object into a `HashSet` or as a key within a `Dictionary`. In these cases you have to ensure that the hash code won't be changed as long as it is stored in such a container. This can either be ensured manually, by simply taking care of this issue when you program or you could provide some `Freeze()` method to your object. If this is called any subsequent try to set a property would lead to some kind of exception (also you should then provide some `Defrost()` method). Additionally you put the call of the `Freeze()` method into your `GetHashCode()` implementation and so you can be quite sure that nobody alter a frozen object by mistake.

And just one last tip: If you need to alter a object within such a container, simply remove it, alter it (don't forget to defrost it) and re-add it again.

Answer (score 1):

You sort of need to choose between mutability and GetHashCode returning the same value for 'equal' objects. Often when you think you want to implement 'equal' for mutable objects, you end up later deciding that you have "shades of equal" and really didn't mean Object.Equals equality.

Having a mutable object as the 'key' in any sort of data structure is a big red flag to me. For example:

```
MyObj a = new MyObj("alpha");
MyObj b = new MyObj("beta");
HashSet<MyObj> objs = new HashSet<MyObj>();
objs.Add(a);
objs.Add(b);
// objs.Count == 2
b.SomeValue = "alpha";
// objs.Distinct().Count() == 1, objs.Count == 2
```

We've badly violated the contract of `HashSet<T>`. This is an obvious example, there are subtle ones.